# audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

There is quit of similar OPs per googles but I didn't fix my issue by following them. It seems I'm closed but still cannot figure out where is wrong, appreciate any hint here.

My AudioPlayer is put in a separate file as Singleton pattern

```
class AudioPlayer {
    // Singleton to keep audio continue to play when switching viewControllers
    static let shared = AudioPlayer()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    private init() {}
    
    func play(url: URL) {
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in PlayerViewController as the playing scene. I put `player.delegate = self`.
And put delegate method in below. I debug and found `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` is not get called.

```
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        AudioPlayer.shared.player?.delegate = self
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            print("EAT")
            goNextTrack()
        } else {
            fatalError("the audio doesn't finished playing successfully.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this before you call `play` it as

```
AudioPlayer.shared.player?.delegate = self // here player is nil and delegate won't work 
AudioPlayer.shared.play(url:////)
```

is not same as

```
AudioPlayer.shared.play(url:////)  
AudioPlayer.shared.player?.delegate = self  // here player has a value  and delegate will work
```

Comment: Yes. The problem here is `AudioPlayer.shared.player?.delegate = self` was called before player is initialized `player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)`. Thank you, I think I'm really close to the problem but simply couldn't found it though.